# How to handle objective convergence, early stopping and learning rate adjustments when using partial_fit method of Scikit SGDClassifier?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am using [partial_fit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.partial_fit) function from SGDClassifier with `log` loss to do online learning as I have a large dataset that cannot fit inside the memory as following:

```py
cls = SGDClassifier(loss='log', learning_rate='adaptive', eta0=0.1, penalty='l2', alpha=0.0001)

for batch in training_generator:
    cls.partial_fit(batch)

predictions = []
for batch in test_data:
    probs = cls.predict_proba(batch)
    predictions += list(probs)
```

In the documentation of `partial_fit` function it is stated

> Internally, this method uses `max_iter = 1`. Therefore, it is not guaranteed that a minimum of the cost function is reached after calling it once. Matters such as objective convergence, early stopping, and learning rate adjustments should be handled by the user.

**Questions:**

1. `max_iter = 1` means I would need to loop through the `partial_fit` as many times as needed by myself for each batch of data as following?

```
for batch in training_generator:
    for _ in range(num_of_iteration):
       cls.partial_fit(batch)
```

2. Does that statement in the documentation mean I would need to compute the [log_loss](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html?highlight=log%20loss#sklearn.metrics.log_loss) (learning curve) myself for the validation data in each training iteration and decide when to stop the training? For example, the code as below.

```py
for batch in training_generator:
    cls.partial_fit(batch)

    predictions = []
    for batch in training_generator:
        probs = cls.predict_proba(batch)
        predictions += list(probs)
    training_loss = log_loss(y_true, predictions)

    predictions = []
    for batch in validation_generator:
        probs = cls.predict_proba(batch)
        predictions += list(probs)
    val_loss = log_loss(y_true, predictions)

    #Pseudocode
    If val_loss does not decrease after n iteration by some value, then stop training
```

3. If I have a large validation and training dataset, can I use a representative subset of the validation and training dataset, i.e: having the same distribution of classes as the full dataset, to compute the loss?
4. If assuming the validation loss keep decreasing and all the data in the `training_generator` has came to the end. Should I shuffle the `training_generator` data and run again the training loop?

```py
#Psedocode
while True:
    Run training loop
    If val_loss does not decrease after n iteration by some value, then stop training (break while loop)
    Finish training loop
```

5. The documentation says that the `learning_rate` adjustment should also be done by the user. Does that mean the `learning_rate='adaptive'` argument to the SGDClassifier has no effect when using `partial_fit`? If yes, how can the `learning_rate` be adjusted?